General Solutions to Probabilistic Systems
Suppose we have a system like this (the actual numbers and structure don't matter):
$$
P(a_1) = 0.28, P(a_2) = 0.36, P(a_3) = 0.41,\\
P(a_1 \cup a_2) = 0.59, P(a_1 \cup a_3) = 0.6, P(a_2 \cup a_3) = 0.66,\\
P(a_1 \cap a_2 \cap a_3) = 0.01
$$
and we want to find $P(a_1 | \overline{a_2} \cap \overline{a_3})$.
I learned how to solve problems like these in my stats course last fall, but it always bugged me that the way we were taught was pretty much to brute force it with trail and error. I tried writing some Prolog code to solve things like this automatically, but it never went anywhere.
Is there some way to do this more generally or algorithmically? Plug in the probabilities for a few variables, and some probabilities for the relations between them, and get a response back out?
What are these types of problems even called, at a higher level?
Thanks!

You can view it as a system of linear equations in variables representing the probabilities of each of the smallest regions of the Venn diagram of the events.

Please note my notation $P(a_1')=1-P(a_1)$ as I use the prime to mean conjugate.
You can do this numerically using De Morgan's laws, but it is a bit involved:
$P(a_1\cap a_2)=P(a_1)+p(a_2)-P(a_1\cup a_2)=0.28+0.36-0.59=0.05$
$P(a_1\cap a_3)=P(a_1)+p(a_3)-P(a_1\cup a_3)=0.28+0.41-0.6=0.09$
$P(a_1\cap a_2'\cap a_3')=P(a_1)-P(a_1\cap a_2)-P(a_1\cap a_3)+P(a_1\cap a_2\cap a_3)=0.28-0.05-0.09+0.01=0.15$
The final line I will admit I used a diagram to make sure I got correct areas, but there are established formulas for these combinations.
